# Storing cooked rice in fridge

Tags: food-safety, storage-method

I ordered a rice recipe yesterday and stored the left over in the fridge. However the container is not airtight. I was planning to have it today and tomorrow. I wanted to ask if its still safe to eat. It was kept in fridge within an hour of ordering.

Comment: Ordered as in from a takeaway?

Comment: Yeah .. kind of .. they delivered it home

Comment: It has few pieces of hard white stuff (little bigger than size of rice grain) .. is that rice that's too dry now .. or is it spoiled ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I asked if it was from a take away is whether or not it was cooked beforehand then reheated to order.

Chances are the restaurant has cooked a large batch of rice, cooled it and then reheated it for your order. If this is the case I would rather lick my toilet seat than reheat the rice again.

Why?

1. There is a bacteria spore (Bacillus cereus) that can live inside each grain of rice which can't be killed by boiling, also present in beans. The killing of this bacteria requires 120c (i think) which is only achieved under pressure (think canned foods). When the rice is then reheated again it's giving this bacteria more chance of growth, each time you heat it, leaving behind toxins.
2. Take away are notoriously bad for sticking to safety guidelines. Possibly allowing the rice to cool on the side in the kitchen or a stuck straight in the fridge. Where is is a **must** you cool the rice to fridge temp within 30mins. I'd personally always cool my rice under running water and ice. But I don't cook Chinese food and I imagine this would wash away much of the starch required for that 'sticky' Chinese style rice.
3. The warm time between them cooking the rice originally, then the time after reheating it, packaging it, delivering it to your door, you dishing it up and leaving it on your counter while you eat and only then putting it in the fridge... Bah tummy bug in a tub if you ask me.
4. We have no idea how long this rice was kept in the fridge at the place in question. Could be fresh that day but there's every chance it's older anything up to 3 days (hopefully no longer) which is way past the recommend 24 hours.

When people complain about getting ill from the Chinese/Indian they had the night before because of the prawns. Really more often than not it is the rice making them sick not the meat.

So the short version...

...bin it.

Comment: Most places pre cook rice so they don't have to wait so long during service, imagine trying to cook 100+ portions of rice during service. Top restaurants will do it to order but they won't do takeaway. Also for Chinese rice it requires cooling cooked rice then frying it they never do it with fresh rice.

Comment: I deleted the comment on restaurant .. thinking it would be redundant .. still .. thank you for your answer ! :)

Comment: Safety advice here: https://www.nhs.uk/common-health-questions/food-and-diet/can-reheating-rice-cause-food-poisoning/